# Task throws UnobservedTaskException in rare occasions only and kills iis process

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Task, in very rare occasions throws UnobservedTaskException and kills the iis process. I could not successfully reproduce it as it happens very rarely and randomly. After some research I found out that the Task is garbage collected somehow. But I am holding the reference to the task anyway so this should not happen.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    processor.DoSomeLongRunningProcess();       
});

var endTask = task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCanceled)
    {
        Loggger.Log("Cancelled");
        UpdateStatusToDb(Cancelled);
    }
    else if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        if (t.Exception != null)
        {
            Loggger.Log("Faulted", e.Exception);
            UpdateStatusToDb("Faulted", e.Exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            Loggger.Log("Faulted");
            UpdateStatusToDb("Faulted", "No Exception but Faulted");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateStatusToDb("Successful");
    }
}, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
```

Any idea why?

Edit:
I am deliberately throwing some Exception inside `DoSomeLongRunningProcess()`. Those Exceptions are pending inside Task and thrown after some time I guess.

Comment: What do you mean "I am holding the reference to the task anyway" ?  What code exactly is keeping the reference, and in what context does it execute?

Comment: The reference of `task` and `endTask`* here are held. `endTask` should complete its code even when task is throwing some exception. But the code inside `endTask` is prematurely stopped in some occasions where previous `task` execution resulted in exception.

Comment: Please specify where task and endTask are held. For example, are they held by code that executes within the ASP.NET pipeline while handling an HTTP request?  If that is the case, they are probably not held for very long.  Or is your code snip from something else, like a desktop application or a service?

Comment: Task is initiated by asp.net code behind.

Comment: Capture IIS worker process crash dump with Debug Diagnostics or Windows Error Reporting. Analyzing the dumps can easily show what's up.